# OpenCV: cvLoadImage opens 16-bit image as 8-bit

Tags: image, opencv

I am trying to process 16-bit single-channel uncompressed TIFF images with OpenCV 2.1, but when I call cvLoadImage, apparently they get converted to 8-bit:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("myImage.tif",
      CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);

std::cout << img->depth << std::endl;
```

prints

```
8
```

The images have been produced by a fluorescence scanner that generates only this kind of images, and I have confirmed with a commercial software package that they really are 16-bit.

How can I open these images and work with the original bit depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... you could write your own code to load the image. Its uncompressed TIFF, so shouldn't be much trouble.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh! Thank you very much for your answer. I've been working with OpenCV only for a couple of months. Could you give me a hint about how to do that?

Comment: Loading an image isn't an OpenCV thing. You can use fopen and related functions to open the file and load the image pixels. Or you can try libtiff.

Answer (score 5):

In OpenCV Loading a tif image (16 bits for example) in python should work by typing:

```
im = cv.LoadImageM("test.tif",cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: +1 Works for other OpenCV languages as well (tested with C++)

Answer (score 1):

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1, this version allows opening images of 16 bits like jpromvi made:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("myImage.tif",
      CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (using OpenCV 2.x on Linux, with the latest libtiff). I was actually using 12bit tiff Images, which does not make it easier...

I can recommend ImageMagic.

You can verify that your image is really 16bit

> > display myImage.tiff (right click, "Image Info")

I converted it to png - which worked perfectly in my case

> > convert myImage.tiff myImage.png

Answer (score 0):

use GDAL lib to open 16 bit tiff image, and then convert gdal dataset to opencv Mat

see:
https://github.com/marvins/Code_Sandbox/blob/master/c%2B%2B/opencv/geo_tools/gdalToOpenCV.cpp