# Different Pixel Values in MATLAB and C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I see there are similar questions to this but don't quiet answer what I am asking so here is my question.

In C++ with OpenCV I run the code I will provide below and it returns an average pixel value of 6.32. However, when I open the image and use the mean function in MATLAB it returns an average pixel intensity of approximately 6.92ish. As you can see I convert the OpenCV values to double to try to ease this issue and have found that openCV loads the image as a set of integers whereas MATLAB loads the image as decimal values that are approximately but not quite the same obviously as the integers. So my question is, being new to coding, which is correct? I'm assuming MATLAB is returning more accurate values and if that is the case I would like to know if there is a way to load the images in the same fashion to avoid the discrepancy.

Thank you, Code below

```
    Mat img = imread("Cells2.tif");
cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::imshow("stuff",img);
Mat dst;
if(img.channels() == 3)
{
    img.convertTo(dst, CV_64FC1);
}
else if (img.channels() == 1) 
{
    img.convertTo(dst, CV_64FC1);
}
cv::imshow("output",dst/255);
int NumPixels = img.total();


double avg;
double c = 0; 
double std;
    for(int y = 0; y < dst.cols; y++)
    { 

        for(int x = 0; x < dst.rows; x++)
        {
            c+=dst.at<double>(x,y)*255;
        }
    }

avg = c/NumPixels;
cout << "asfa = " << c << endl;
double deviation;

double var;
double z = 0;
double q;
    //for(int a = 0; a<= img.cols; a++)
for(int y = 0; y< dst.cols; y++)
    {
        //for(int b = 0; b<= dst.rows; b++)
        for(int x = 0; x< dst.rows; x++)
        {
            q=dst.at<double>(x,y);

            deviation = q - avg;
            z = z + pow(deviation,2);
            //cout << "q = " << q << endl;
        }

    }

var = z/(NumPixels);
std = sqrt(var);
cv::Scalar avgPixel = cv::mean(dst);

cout << "Avg Value = " << avg << endl;
cout << "StdDev = " << std << endl;
cout << "AvgPixel =" << avgPixel;

cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: MATLAB may be detecting the range of pixel values by assuming the highest value is 100% brightness.  If the brightest value is about 233, this would explain the difference.

Comment: Is there a way to account for and stop the discrepancy?

Comment: Can you show your Matlab code for calculating the average pixel intensity of an image?

Comment: I'm just using A = theimagefile.tif
then using the prebuilt mean(A(:)).

Comment: thanks, is your test image color or grayscale?

Comment: You mean you use `A=imread(theimagefile.tif)` and `mean(A(:))`? I posted my answer.

Comment: @VeniVici: It would help to know more about your image.. Please report the output of the following in MATLAB: `info = imfinfo('Cells2.tif'), img = imread('Cells2.tif'); whos img`. Also show you current MATLAB code, we need to know whether you are doing the same RGB to grayscale conversion.

Comment: whos('A')
  Name  A         Size 332x332                 Bytes   220448  Class    uint16      Attributes

            

using iminfo is returning an error for undefined input type char.
The only thing I did in Matlab was 
A = ('Cells2.tif') with the full file destination instead and then
Q = mean(A(:)).

Comment: @VeniVici: see my answer below

Comment: @VeniVici: here is a question related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263050/opencv-cvloadimage-opens-16-bit-image-as-8-bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your comment, the image seems to be stored with a 16-bit depth. MATLAB loads the TIFF image as is, while by default [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) will load images as 8-bit. This might explain the difference in precision that you are seeing.

Use the following to open the image in OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("file.tif", cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH|cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
```

In MATLAB, it's simply:

```
img = imread('file.tif');
```

---

Next you need to be aware of the data type you are working with. In OpenCV its CV_16U, in MATLAB its `uint16`. Therefore you need to convert types accordingly.

For example, in MATLAB:

```
img2 = double(img) ./ double(intmax('uint16'));
```

would convert it to a `double` image with values in the range [0,1]

Comment: you could do a similar conversion in OpenCV using: `img.convertTo(img2, CV_64F, 1.0/65535);`

Comment: YESSSSS thank you so much man this worked it was that conversion issue right there. This has been driving me insane thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are converting the image if certain conditions are met, this can change some color values while MATLAB can choose to not convert the image but use the raw image
2. colors are mostly represented in hex format with popular implementations in the format of 0xAARRGGBB or 0xRRGGBBAA, so 32 bit integers will do (unsigned/signed doesn't matter, the hex value is still the same), create a 64 bit variable, add all the 32 bit variables together and then divide by the amount of pixels, this will get you a quite accurate result (for images up to 16384 by 16384 pixels (where a 32 bit value is representing the color of one pixel), if larger, then a 64 bit integer will not be enough).

   ```
   long long total = 0;
   long long divisor = image.width * image.height;
   for(int x = 0; x < image.width; ++x)
   {
       for(int y = 0; x < image.height; ++x)
       {
           total += image.at(x,y).color;
       }
   }
   double avg = total / divisor;
   std::cout << "Average color value: " << avg << std::endl;
   ```

Comment: No.  You need to treat the color planes separately, but in this method they interfere with each other (both carries during addition and the fraction part during division will end up in other color planes and corrupt the result)

Comment: Yeah, this was returning a wonky result after I tried to edit it to make it run. I appreciate the help either way but it was of no use :(.

Comment: maybe if you tell what the results was or where it's gone wrong I could edit it and fix ? :) I'm here to help man ^.^

Comment: The code will not compile below I tried to fix what I could but dst (converted image to gray float) says that it requires a class type and I'm not sure how to fix it.
      long long total = 0;

long long divisor = dst.cols * dst.rows;

for(int x = 0; x < dst.cols; ++x)

{

    for(int y = 0; x < dst.rows; ++x)

    {

        total += dst.at<uchar>(x,y).color;

    }

}

double avg = total / divisor;

std::cout << "Average color value: " << avg << std::endl;

Comment: Not sure how to better format this in a comment still new to stack :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the image, you must use similar methods in both environments (MATLAB and OpenCV) to avoid possible conversions which may be done by default in either environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what difficulty you are having with mean value in Matlab versus OpenCV. If I understand your question correctly, your goal is to implement Matlab's `mean(image(:))` in OpenCV. For example in Matlab you do the following:

```
>> image = imread('sheep.jpg')
>> avg = mean(image(:))

ans =

   119.8210
```

Here's how you do the same in OpenCV:

```
Mat image = imread("sheep.jpg");
Scalar avg_pixel;
avg_pixel = mean(image);
float avg = 0;
cout << "mean pixel (RGB): " << avg_pixel << endl;

for(int i; i<image.channels(); ++i) {
    avg = avg + avg_pixel[i]; 
}
avg = avg/image.channels();
cout << "mean, that's equivalent to mean(image(:)) in Matlab: " << avg << endl;
```

OpenCV console output:

> ```
> mean pixel (RGB): [77.4377, 154.43, 127.596, 0]
> mean, that's equivalent to mean(image(:)) in Matlab: 119.821
> ```

So the results are the same in Matlab and OpenCV.

**Follow up**
Found some problems in your code.

- OpenCV stores data differently from Matlab. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139210/1121420) for a rough explanation on how to access a pixel in OpenCV. For example:

  ```
  // NOT a correct way to access a pixel in CV_F32C3 type image
  double pixel = image.at<double>(x,y); 

  //The correct way (where the pixel value is stored in a vector)
  // Note that Vec3d is defined as: typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
  Vec3d pixel = image.at<Vec3d>(x, y);
  ```
- Another error I found

  ```
  if(img.channels() == 3)
  {
      img.convertTo(dst, CV_64FC1); //should be CV_64FC3, instead of CV_64FC1
  }
  ```

Accessing `Mat` elements may be confusing. I suggest getting a book on OpenCV to get started, for example [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244), and read [OpenCV tutorials and documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Bah thank you for finding those silly errors. However, the image is grayscale which is all well and good your code will just spit out the vector 6.321 which *255 is equal to 1612 (which is what my really poorly coded mean for loops found as well). However, in MATLAB this same picture is giving a mean of 1776. I see for your picture it gave the same average. Why is mine returning such a different value? It's a grayscale .tif if that helps.

Comment: I just attempted it with lena.bmp and put it in grayscale in matlab and OpenCV and in openCV my handwritten code and cv::mean(img) return a value of 95.6564 where MATLAB returns 96.5... I have no idea haha.

Comment: so, you first convert an image to grayscale and then compute its average?

Comment: The tif is in grayscale already, for Lena I leave as 3 channel and follow your code above to compute the average. These are the values I posted. MATLAB is returning higher values than those computed in OpenCV. The only MATLAB I'm doing is loading the image and taking the mean through mean(A(:)).

Comment: Just use the code that I gave you in my answer and convert your test image to grayscale using `cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);` before computing the average . When you test your code in Matlab for color image lena.bmp don't forget to convert the image to grayscale using `image = rgb2gray(image)` and then do `mean(image(:))`. I'm getting the same results in both Matlab and Opencv.