# Open a multichannel image in Python OpenCV2

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a 4 band multichannel image (TIF) which is an unsigned 16 bit image. I am using the following:

```
    opencv2 
    python
```

I have done the following at the beginning of my code

```
    import cv2
```

When I use

```
  i = cv2.imread('img.tif')
```

it is reading all the four bands but as UINT8. When I use

```
  i = cv2.imread('img.tif', cv2.CV_16U)
```

it reads only one channel of the image. What should be done to read all the four channels in 16bit unsigned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9781142/749973

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I asked a Python related question!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the flag `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH`. The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) states this flag will:

> If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.

```
i = cv2.imread('img.tif', flags=cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

If that doesn't work, try the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag instead. It's not documented, but it looks like it may also work.

Comment: Nope this does **not** work. My image loads but only one channel! I have cross verfied this with Matlab where my image loads as UINT16 / 4 channel.

Comment: It appears that `GDAL` from `osgeo` works better in terms of reading images.

Comment: @Indian Did you try the `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag? It works for me.